# access a dropbox file without having to login using appkey and secret key

Tags: iphone, sdk, dropbox

I need to implement the following functionality:
*send name and e-mail address of an user to an excel sheet in Dropbox.As soon as the user submits details,the data needs to get appended to the file.

i have made an app account in my dropbox, and got its key and secret, which is hardcoded in the app.Want to get rid of the login screen.How is it to be done?
Kindly provide some code examples as Im a newbie.

Comment: how can you access a dropbox file without logging in ??

Comment: I want to login to dropbox in the back-end.I do not want the login window to display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible now but may be in future.

[Just refer this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#authorize)

In DropBoxSDK, Because the application doesn't call /oauth/authorize directly, there is no direct return value. After the user authorizes the application, use its request token to retrieve an access token via the /oauth/access_token API call.